# Odoo 10 : Remove or disable the New Message function

Tags: python, module, odoo

Can somebody give a hint how to remove/disable the New message button in contacts module??It doesnt seem to be part of form view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to remove the button .Added a new template to add the css:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
    <!-- Adds all assets in Odoo -->
        <template id="assets_backend" name="contacts assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <!--These links will be called when loading your Odoo -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/contacts_custom/static/css/css.css"/> 

            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And the css is :

```
.o_chatter_button_new_message
                {
                display:none !important;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via JS and CSS. In this that button has a one unique class **`o_chatter_button_new_message`** Remove this class by adding CSS `display:NONE`

Comment: I couldnt find this class. Where can i find it?

Comment: That is located under '`addons/mail/static/src/xml/chatter.xml`'

Comment: can i extend this template to modify it ? i dont want to make any changes in defualt modules

Comment: Yes you can do this

Comment: but this template doesnt have any id

Comment: You can use `t-name` for that.

Answer (score 0):

That is the chatter widget. You could find it in the view to remove it. Search for something like this:

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

You could remove it from that view using something like this:

```
<record id="remove_partner_chatter_box" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mail.view_emails_partner_info_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_chatter"]' position='replace'>
            <p>XxXXXXXX</p>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I tried to remove this div element in my custom module using xpath but didnt work :<record id="chatter_box" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="model">account.asset.asset</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_asset.view_account_asset_asset_form" />
      <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_chatter"]' position='replace'>
    <p>XxXXXXXX</p>
            </xpath>
      </field>
</record>

Comment: is there a different way to remove widgets from view ?

Comment: You need to inherit the proper view, not any view, `view_account_asset_asset_form` it's not a view related to `res.partner` which is the Contact. The chatter widget is introduced by the mail module so the partner view extension that contain the chatter is located in the view `mail.view_emails_partner_info_form` that you could see at: 

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/mail/views/res_partner_views.xml#L16

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented earlier on this post, it is part of chatter widget. In Odoo v12, it is fully displayed in this way:

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

Sending a message and logging a note are included within "mail_thread" widget,
scheduling an activity lies under "mail_activity", and the right side buttons (attachments and followers) are stacked within "mail_followers".

By inheriting the model "mail.thread" in the own model, just adding the widget snippet in the given .xml form view omitting the lines of what you want to hide just works fine.

To get more accurate about hidding part by part separately (i.e. hide followers but still show attaching button) I guess it needs to be dealt with JS side, but still giving some tries.

Hope it still helps.